# Is saving a list of strings to CSV and read it as list (of strings) again possible?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I've encountered an awkward problem: I want to parse a big csv file, capsule some of it's information (including a list of keywords, 'err') and store the content to another csv-file.

What I do is the following:

```
with open('auswertung.json', 'w') as raus:
craus = csv.DictWriter(raus, ['entr', 'yr', 'err', 'lang', 'status',
    'plat', 'os'], dialect='unix')
craus.writeheader()
leser = csv.reader(f)

for z in leser:
    problems = []
    kat = {'entr': z[0], 'yr': int(z[0][4:8]), 'err': None, 'lang': None,
            'status': z[1], 'plat': None, 'os': None}

    kat['err'] = ['one', 'two', 'three']

more stuff
craus.writerow(kat)
```

However, the module stores 'err' as

```
"['one', 'two', 'three']"
```

when I try to read it with DictReader in another program. That's a string... casting it with list() creates a list with all the letters as list members.

Is this a bug or is it not intended to store lists of values with csv? How can I fix this?

The 'unix' style was just an experiment. Default style doesn't change anything

Comment: maybe try reading as `for z in dict(leser):`..?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bug

Certainly not.

You may find that JSON is a better fit for your needs than CSV format, z.B. die name 'auswertung.json' suggests you've already started exploring this. The writer will call `str()` on each element as it serializes it to a CSV. You may find that [`dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) (or dump) is your friend.

If you're willing to `$ pip install pandas`, you may find that [`pd.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is a convenient way to serialize a bunch of rows (or `pd.to_json()`).

Style nit: it would be preferable to list one value per line:

```
    kat = dict(entr=z[0],
               yr=int(z[0][4:8]),
               err=None,
               lang=None,
               status=z[1],
               plat=None,
               os=None)
```

Comment: For CSV everything, even numbers, lists etc. are converted into strings, is this how that works? Appears a bit awkward to me, but ok

Except json (which needs far more space than csv), do you know a recommended workaround? I need to store a list with strings per entry, and the list's length could in theory be dozens of chars long

As for the style, ack. Though I got the feeling as if the pythonic way is to save space all the time, as with `a, b = my_func()`

Comment: There is little difference between writing a ten-column .CSV file and using the json module to write ten-element lists as JSON lines, at least if the elements are numbers & text as one is accustomed to viewing in Excel. Add dicts & lists and you will start to see the support that `.loads()` offers for automatically de-serializing to the proper type is quite convenient. If disk space is a concern then I recommend pyarrow for a DataFrame serialized with parquet: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet Very convenient!